# Can't get Rails 3 Active Scaffold Nested Forms/Records to work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested, scaffold

Rather detail my own record set, which is simple but has a lot of fields and sub-records, I'd just like to be able to get the example given on github to work, i.e. https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API%3A-Nested

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contacts
end

# app/models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

# app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :contacts do | config |
  end
end

# app/controllers/companies_controller.rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  active_scaffold :companies do |config|
    config.nested.add_link("Company's contacts", [:contacts])
  end
end
```

Obviously the contacts table has a column for company_id (i.e. foreign key).

'As is', it appears that in the companies controller, the 'companies' needs to be 'company'. So after that change, the config.nested... line causes the following error:-

Routing Error
undefined method `add_link' for nil:NilClass

After trying (and failing) to fix this I just commented it out and it works quite well, however I need a one to one (or none) relationship, so made the change (contacts had to change to contact, Rails objects otherwise) :-

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one:contact
end
```

It appears to work but when a contact is updated, it makes a mess of the form, displaying the updated contact at the top of the form, just under the field labels that actually belong to the records below, i.e. the company records. It also allows more than one contact to be created when a company record is created, but this may be constrained by another method, or possibly fixed if the config.nested.add_link works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just use this (it's in the same link you posted):

```
config.nested.add_link(:contacts, :label => "Company's contacts", :page => true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I never checked back, as such I ended up using ActiveAdmin instead, which worked fairly well.